# SwiftUI with Charts - Lost ability to work with setValue formatting

Tags: charts, swiftui

I am using Charts with SwiftUI and almost everything is working fine.

I followed this excellent tutorial.

https://medium.com/@zzzzbh/plotting-in-ios-using-charts-framework-with-swiftui-222034a2bea6

But I have lost the ability to format anything to do with the values.  I cant change the font size, format or color.

here they should be formatted with %, red color and bigger font.

Everything else works as it should.

Is this a Xcode issue? Anyone else have same experience?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

[image]

```
func addData(barChart: BarChartView ) -> BarChartData {
    
    let data = BarChartData()
    
    let dataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: entries)
    
    dataSet.label = "Returns"
    
    let pFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    pFormatter.numberStyle = .percent
    pFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    pFormatter.multiplier = 1
    pFormatter.percentSymbol = "%"
      
    let l = barChart.legend
    l.enabled = false
      
    let fontValue = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: .light )

    data.barWidth = Double(0.666)
      
    // nothing I do here will effect the formatting on the chart.

    data.setValueTextColor(NSUIColor.red)
    data.setValueFont(fontValue)
    data.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: pFormatter))
      
    data.addDataSet(dataSet)
    
    return data
    
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The formatting of the charts is to do with the `Charts` package and nothing to do with SwiftUI. I'd advise you to consult their documentation for formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that the

```
data.addDataSet(dataSet)
```

needs to be moved above the formatted data.

good luck.